# How to replace values from one yaml file to another?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, yaml

I'm trying to replace some values from specific fields from one YAML file to another.

I have 2 different folders structures.

```
├── helm -> root folder
    ├── accounting-pl.yaml
    ├── Chart.yaml
        ├── charts
        ├── templates
        │   ├── NOTES.txt
        │   ├── _helpers.tpl
        │   ├── deployment.yaml
        │   ├── ingress.yaml
        │   ├── service.yaml
        │   └── tests
        │       └── test-connection.yaml
        └── values.yaml
    └── unplse
        ├── Chart.yaml
        ├── charts
        ├── templates
        │   ├── NOTES.txt
        │   ├── _helpers.tpl
        │   ├── deployment.yaml
        │   ├── ingress.yaml
        │   ├── service.yaml
        │   └── tests
        │       └── test-connection.yaml
        └── values.yaml
    ....... and so son
```

and

```
├── yaml -> root folder
    ├── accounting-pl.yaml
    ├── bi-client-svc.yaml
    ├── bi-cltscreen.yaml
    ├── bi-cnsm-lispl.yaml
    ├── bi-cnsm-unpl.yaml
    ├── bi-cons-unpl.yaml
    ├── bi-consumers.yaml
    ├── bi-data-svc.yaml
    ├── bi-datareten.yaml
    ├── clapserver.yaml
    ├── client.yaml
    ├── cn-p24.yaml
    ├── cn-payu.yaml
    ├── consent.yaml
    ├── debt-coll-pl.yaml
    ├── document.yaml
    ├── ds-falcon-bare.yaml
    ├── ds-slackme.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m0563c0.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m18d452.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m1d681c.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m30b4b3.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m459e80.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m48a063.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m50eacc.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m57043d.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m5fb04b.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m69bc21.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m6edd4b.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m706b21.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m7fb269.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m802936.yaml
    ├── ds-ss-m8aa1c3.yaml
```

inside the values.yaml file there is the field `replicaCount: 1`
inside of each of this YAML files like `ds-ss-m7fb269.yaml` (inside the yaml root folder) there is the field `desiredCount: x`

How can I get the value of this field `desiredCount` and paste in `replicaCount`?  E.g. `replicaCount: 44`

I tried many things but failed in all of them.
This is what I tried so far.

```
def get_replicaCount():
    for root, dir, files in os.walk('.', topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name == "values.yaml":
                with open(os.path.join(root, name), 'rt') as helm:
                    try:
                        lyamls = yaml.safe_load(helm)
                        print(lyamls['replicaCount'])
                    except Exception as err:
                       print(err)
```

it prints all the `replicaCount` values

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

...and so on

```
def get_desiredCount():
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        with open('yaml/' + i, 'r') as f:
            loaded = yaml.safe_load(f)
            print(loaded['service']['desiredCount'])
```

get all the `desiredCount` values and print them.

```
4
3
9
12
and so son...
```

How could I replace these values?

Comment: It's not clear how a given `values.yaml` file maps to a yaml file in the `yaml` directory.

Comment: I wondered why both of your python segments were invalid code and why you had both of your root folders unindented, but you probably didn't try the formatting buttons, or help, to get that proper indentation of the whole block (select block, press Ctrl+K). Please review my edit to see if it represents what you want.

Comment: 1) YAML has mappings with keys and associated values, not "fields"; 2) `desiredCount` and `replicaCount` are keys, not values (the numbers are values); 3) It looks like you have many more values for the key `desiredCount` than `values.yaml` files, if so **how** do you want them to be replaced? Or are there exactly the same amount of `value.yaml` files as files under the root folder `yaml`?

Comment: there are exactly the same amount of values.yaml files for each *.yaml file under root yaml folder.